# initial the structure array. Why execute the result have redundance value?

Tags: c

example:

declare struct:

```
struct table
{
    char r1[6];
    char r2[2];
    char r3[6];
};

/* main */

int main()
{
     struct table t[10];
      int i;
      f010_Initial (t);
      for (i=0; i<10 ; i++)
      {
        printf ("%5s %5s %5s\n", t[i].r1,t[i].r2, t[i].r3);
      }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/* initial struct */ 

void f010_Initial (struct table t[10])
{
    int i;
      for (i=0; i<10; i++)
      {

        strncpy (t[i].r1, "aaaaaa", 6);
          t[i].r1[6] = '\0';

        strncpy (t[i].r2, "aa", 2);
          t[i].r1[2] = '\0';

        strncpy (t[i].r3, "aaaaaa", 6);
          t[i].r3[6] = '\0';
      }
}
```

why execute is  this:

aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
 aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa

Comment: You should much more often use `sizeof`: `strncpy(t[i].r3, "aaaaaa", sizeof t[i].r3-1);` and `t[i].r3[sizeof t[i].r3-1] = '\0';` will allow you to change the size of your arrays without doing harm.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare `char r1[6];` you can't then do this: `t[i].r1[6] = '\0';` - your array has 6 elements so the highest element index you can access is 5. To do otherwise is to write off the end of your array and then all bets are off. You're actually lucky it didn't do something worse than it did!

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate an extra character in each array to hold the `0` terminator. So, change your struct definition to

```
struct table
{
    char r1[7];
    char r2[3];
    char r3[7];
};
```

Once you have done this, it is correct to insert the terminator at the final position with

```
t[i].r1[6] = '\0';
```

as you are already doing. (The array index is zero-based, so the seven entries are at positions `r1[0]` through to `r1[6]`.)

Answer (score 0):

Take care here, for example you have char `r1[6];` but you shouldn't be referencing `r1[6]` as it's out of the array range: you should use `r1[0] to r1[5]`. In this particular case, `r1[6]` is probably pointing to `r2[0]` given the way your struct is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

check the function properly you are rewriting `r[1]` twice , also please check the structure index , you are overflowing , if struct size of 6 can be indexed from 0 to 5 can't be 6 .